# How can I use bind, on, unbind and off in one function jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use bind, on, unbind and off in the same function jQuery? Is it possible?

For example:

```
    //It works.
    
    $(window).on("wheel", function(){
        alert("It works!");
    });
```

```
    //It doesn't work.
    
    $(window).bind("wheel").on("wheel").unbind("wheel").off("wheel", function(){
        alert("It doesn't work!");
    });
```

I want to use the same function to the four events.

Comment: `$(window).bind("wheel").on("wheel").unbind("wheel").off("wheel", function(){` - maybe you should tell us what your end goal is, because that chaining makes NO sense :\

Comment: I think you should read the doc of those 4 functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first understand how jQuery works.

```
$("#element-id").bind('wheel', function() {})
```

Just pick `#element-id`, bind an event handler (Your anonymous function) to 'wheel' event, and return `#element-id` again.

In your code, you are not doing anything.

```
$("#element").bind('event-name', handlerFunction)
```

Is the same of:

```
$("#element").on('event-name', handlerFunction)
```

And

```
$("#element").unbind('event-name')
```

Is the same of

```
$("#element").off('event-name')
```

In `unbind()` and `off()` you may specify a handler function, that is the function to be unbinded.

e.g:

```
$("#element").off('event-name', handlerFunction)
```

If you do not specify, you are unbinding all handlers to that event.

Just take a read in this four links:

- [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
- [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)